# Dynamic connection to second MySQL database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails application that will migrate user content.  I need to take in database parameters via a form and use them to connect to the given database.  What's the best way to achieve this?  I've attempted using `Mysql.real_connect` with no joy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`establish_connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-establish_connection) with your new parameters and then use [`connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-connection) normally.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need in a rake task.
I ended up using basically the following code
after the rails environment had been loaded by rake.

```
require "mysql2"

#Constants
#---------
DB_HOST = "example.com"
DB_USER = "username"
DB_PASSWORD = "password"
DB = "db_name"

SQL = "SELECT * FROM BLAH;"

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => DB_HOST, :username => DB_USER,
                            :password=> DB_PASSWORD, :database => DB)

rs = client.query(SQL)
rs.each do |h|
  #Work on Row here
end
```

It is using mysql (mainly because I got tired of mysql crashing the script), but the process should be the same.

Comment: did you set client in an initializer file, and then just use client.query() from your controllers? I need to do something similar to this, but I am having trouble deciding where the "connection" should be placed so It can be reused. and I'm worried about having too many connections, and connections not closing... can you post example/gist?

Answer (score 0):

Check [ruby/mysql](http://www.tmtm.org/en/ruby/mysql/)

```
require "mysql"
my = Mysql::new("host", "user", "passwd", "db")
res = my.query("select * from tbl")
res.each do |row|
  col1 = row[0]
  col2 = row[1]
end
```