# Dynamic second database Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I want to add a second read-only database to my application based on a variable aside the SQLite file I'm developing with.
So, there should be three databases.
1. Local SQLite file
2. Production Read-only MySQL database
3. Test Read-only MySQL database

This test database has new columns added and will be pushed as production database soon.

From [this SO-Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362772/dynamic-connection-to-second-mysql-database-in-ruby-on-rails), I do not understand what the solution is.
I already use `establish_connection`.

```rb
establish_connection(
        :adapter => 'mysql2',
        :database => "db1",
        :username => "username",
        :password => "p*ssw*rd",
        :host => "ho.st.com"
    )
```

This `db1` is the production db **without** the extra table columns.
`db2` is the test db **with** the extra table columns.

```
establish_connection(
        :adapter => 'mysql2',
        :database => "db2",
        :username => "username",
        :password => "p*ssw*rd",
        :host => "ho.st.com"
    )
```

I thought this could be a solution:

In the models of the tables from the MySQL databases:

```
config = 'test'

case config
  when 'test'
    establish_connection(
        :adapter => 'mysql2',
        :database => "db1",
        :username => "username",
        :password => "p*ssw*rd",
        :host => "ho.st.com"
    )
  else
    establish_connection(
        :adapter => 'mysql2',
        :database => "db2",
        :username => "username",
        :password => "p*ssw*rd",
        :host => "ho.st.com"
    )
end
```

But now I have to edit all 'affected' models when I change the status. Is there a way to variabilise (is that even a word?) this so I only have to edit this config once?

I've tried via Application_controller.rb, but this didn't work.

```
# Application_controller.rb
def get_config_status
  return 'test'
end

# model.rb
config = get_config_status()  #=> undefined method `get_config_status' for Regio(Table doesn't exist):Class
# or
config = Application.get_config_status  #=> uninitialized constant Regio::Application
```

Or should I consider totally something else?
To be honest, I don't like putting usernames and passwords in Models. Is this a possible thread for hackers?

### Summary

What I'm trying to accomplish is:
Set one variable so my application uses db2 instead of db1.

Comment: As you're using rails, is there any reason you're not using config/database.yml?

Comment: Is that a possibility? I do have a MySQL(2) db configured, the database referring in the post is a read-only database hosted somewhere else than my VPS. Some models I use are read from this db. Then, there are some models which are in my 'own' database. This 'own' db is configured in database.yml

Answer (score 0):

The octopus gem might be helpful.

https://github.com/tchandy/octopus

You can select the database at query level,

```
User.where(name: 'Sam').using(:db2)
```

Or you can select the database per controller action,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :select_shard

  def select_shard(&block)
    Octopus.using(:db1, &block)
  end
end
```

Check out the [readme](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) on Github for more examples.

Comment: Thanks, I'will look into that tomorrow.